# Do I need to ask for permission to use tokens?

Tags: internet, international

I know that you need to ask the user for permission to use cookies. However I use OAuth from Google Firebase. OAuth works with tokens instead of cookie-authentication, however, for the user it makes no difference. She/he gets authenticated across pages. Since I didn't find anything regarding "permission for tokens", I assume that I don't need it. Is this right? Any legal proof would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to be compliant with regulations and laws such as the GDPR, you should be asking for permission to use any identifier which is sent between the client and the server with any request, if that identifier allows you to track an individual user.

The [actual text of the GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-4-gdpr/) contains the following definition:

> ‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, ***an identification number***, location data, ***an online identifier*** or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;

This includes:

- **Cookies** (the most obvious one)
- **ETag** (if you are not using an etag value across multiple users, it can be used to identify a single user and thus counts as an online identifier)
- **Bearer tokens** (issued to individual users, so obviously is an online identifier)

amongst many other things.

So yes, you should be asking for consent, and you should be highlighting this in your privacy policy, including how you are using the tokens and what information the token contains (see the website [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to see what information most OAuth tokens have the potential to leak).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove a negative. There is no legal requirement client permission for using OAuth tokens. If there was any legal proof available, it would be to prove, it was required. Since such proof does not exist, you do not need to ask the client permission to use OAuth tokents.

Comment: While it is often difficult to prove a negative, it would help to show why the existing laws mandating cookie permission dont apply to OAuth tokens.

Comment: The GDPR is all about information which can be linked to an individual user - an OAuth token 100% fits that bill.

Answer (score 0):

### The issue doesn’t arise

It’s inherent in the oauth system that permission is asked and if it’s not given, the service doesn’t work.

Comment: The OAuth system does rely on permission to **_issue_** the token, but that doesn't mean that that permission encompasses all **_usage_** of the token - it can be used against any service which recognises the issuer and audience, and the issuer almost always has no control over the consuming service, so ... we have an "implicit" vs "explicit" permission issue here.  The issuer has explicit permission to issue the token for the user, but does the application have implicit permission to use that token against any service it wishes?  And is implicit permission enough here?

Comment: @Moo the token can only be used against the app that issued it and it specifically tells you what permissions you are giving the app against the third party resource

Comment: No, thats a false belief - if I set my consuming service to allow tokens from a given issuer and an audience, it will gladly use that token, regardless of whether the issuer wants me to or not.  The decision on whether or not to accept a token is 100% on the consuming services side, not the issuers.  We have over 400 microservices over 3 separate platforms, and the only thing our services do against the issuer itself is check the public key to validate the signature.  Every other decision about whether to use the token is made internal to the service.  And the validation is optional!

Comment: There are different things in play here - the issuing service (Facebook, Google, Auth0 et al) who may grant different permissions to access data in their own services, and the consuming service (your apps backend) which really only needs to accept the token, and the consuming service can make the decision to use the claims in the token.  Once the token is issued, if the app sends the token to the consuming backend service (not a service provided by the issuer), the issuer is essentially now out of the loop.